# How to solve GTK application warning

Tags: c

I'm new to Gtk and I'm getting this warning when I try to run a simple application that adds two numbers.
Here is the warning:

> (main:7133): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 07:17:55.017: ../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2618: signal 'add_numbers' is invalid for instance '0x559f24bd7180' of type 'GtkButton'

Here is my Code:

```
#include<gtk/gtk.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

static GtkWidget* number1;
static GtkWidget* number2;
static GtkWidget* Add;
static GtkWidget* answer;
void add_numbers(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data);
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    GtkWidget* window;
    GtkWidget* box;

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Maths");

    gtk_window_set_default_size((GtkWindow *)window, 1000, 800);

    box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 10);

    number1 = gtk_entry_new();
    number2 = gtk_entry_new();

    Add = gtk_button_new_with_label("Add");

    answer = gtk_label_new("Answer: ");

    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    g_signal_connect(Add, "add_numbers", G_CALLBACK(add_numbers), NULL);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), box);

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), number1, 0,0,0);

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), number2, 0, 0, 0);

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), Add, 0, 0, 0);

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), answer, 0, 0, 0);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

void add_numbers(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data){
    gint num1, num2;

    num1 = atoi((char *)gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(number1)));
    num2 = atoi((char *)gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(number2)));

    char buffer[32];

    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "Answer: %d", (num1 + num2));

    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(answer), buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the signal for a button is `"clicked"` not `"add_numbers"`. You simply need:

```c
    g_signal_connect(Add, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(add_numbers), NULL);
```

You can see this documented in [Gtk Button](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.Button.html) (though Gtk+4 tries to c++'ize what was normal C in Gtk+2)